# Find a sequence in $l^p$ but not in $l^q$, where $q < p$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm trying to find a sequence that is in $l^p$ but not in $l^q$, where $q < p$. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I will answer a bit more than what the question actually asks for, since the question itself doesn't really give the full picture.

A function can be in $L^p$ but not $L^q$ for $q<p$ if it has a long tail which larger powers shrink. For instance, for $r<0$, $x^r 1_{[1,\infty)}(x)$ is in $L^p$ if and only if $pr<-1$, i.e. $p>-1/r$.

A function can be in $L^p$ but not $L^q$ for $q>p$ if it has a singularity which larger powers amplify. For instance, if $r<0$ then $x^r 1_{(0,1)}(x)$ is in $L^p$ if and only if $pr>-1$, i.e. $p<-1/r$.

Case 1 is only possible on infinite measure spaces; case 2 is only possible on measure spaces which contain sets of arbitrarily small positive measure. The real line has both of these properties. A bounded interval has just the second property. $\mathbb{N}$ with the counting measure (where the $\ell^p$ spaces live) has just the first property.

Comment: That's great, thank you very much!

Comment: What's the function $x^r 1_{(0,1)}(x)$ What does the indicator function do?

Comment: @mavavilj $1_{[1,\infty)}$ isolates just the tail behavior of $x^r$ (so the behavior at zero doesn't impede the integrability). $1_{(0,1)}$ isolates just the singularity at zero of $x^r$ (so the tail doesn't impede the integrability). On $(0,\infty)$, just $x^r$ is never in any $L^p$ space, either the tail or the singularity or both always ruin it.

Answer (score 0):

What about $x_n=(\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{q}}$?

Comment: What if we were asked to find a sequence that is in l^p but for all q<p the sequence is not in l^q.

Comment: I am not sure but I think that would be very similar to ask the greatest rational number that is less then 1.

Comment: We can find such sequences. Since $\frac{1}{n}$ is just on the boundary between convergence and divergence, it is promising to look at sequences such that $\lvert x_n\rvert^p = \dfrac{1}{n\cdot a_n}$, where $(a_n)$ is growing very slowly (slower than any power of $n$), but fast enough to make the series converge. For $q < p$, we then have $\lvert x_n\rvert^q = n^{-\frac{q}{p}}\cdot a_n^{-\frac{q}{p}}$, and if $(a_n)$ is growing slower than any power of $n$, $\sum \lvert x_n\rvert^q = +\infty$. We can (for $n > 1$) for example take $a_n = (\log n)^\alpha$ for any $\alpha > 1$.